# How to show a particular section from a line in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, awk

Let's say I have a file with the following line:

```
[{"name”:”10.0.0.1”,”address":"10.0.0.1”,”subscriptions["all"],"version":"0.0.0”,”timestamp":1450270166},{"name":"10.0.0.2","address":"10.0.0.2","subscriptions":["all"],"version”:”0.0.0”,”timestamp":1450390819}]
```

Here I need to get the output to be something like

```
name:10.0.0.1
name:10.0.0.2
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. Should it be?

Comment: Try `awk -F"," '{print $1}' data | sed 's/\[{//' | sed 's/”//g' | sed 's/"//g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is valid JSON, use `jq`:

```
jq --raw-output '"name: " + .[].name'

jq --raw-output .[].name | sed "s/^/name: /"
```

Or `jshon`:

```
jshon -a -e name -u | sed "s/^/name: /"
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -MJSON -E 'say "name: ", $_->{name} for @{from_json(<>)}'
```

or Ruby:

```
ruby -rjson -e 'JSON.load(STDIN).map{|i| puts "name: " + i["name"]}'
```

If it's not valid JSON but exactly like in your question:

```
perl -n -E 's/“|”/"/g; say "name: $1" while /"name":"(.+?)"/g'
```

All commands expect your input as stdin.

Comment: Never heard about `jshon`, very well done!